# Randomly moving about a lattice, probability that I return to my original location?

Tags: probability, random-walk

I thought of this question when I was walking aimlessly around my neighborhood. Here's my question:

My house is on an infinite lattice of points: say my house is at $(0,0)$. I start walking north (it doesn't matter what direction I start) and when I reach an intersection (at a lattice point) I choose to go left, right, or forward (relative to the direction I'm facing). What's the probability that I end up back at $(0,0)$, my house?

I have a feeling that the probability is $1$ because, very non-mathematically speaking, if I take an infinite amount of steps surely I will end up back at $(0,0)$ *eventually,* right? Also, I know of this problem in 1D, in which case I know the answer is $1$. I would prefer an answer that is intuitive.

Comment: This is a fascinating topic: See the Polya lattice constants for the probability in two and three dimensions.  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolyasRandomWalkConstants.html

Comment: The answer is that you return to the origin almost surely in 2 dimensions, but not in higher dimensions, cf. [Random walks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk#Higher_dimensions).

Answer (score 2):

It really depends also on the probabilities associated to which direction you travel in. If they are all equal, then for 1-d and 2-d such walks, you do come back to the origin. Surprisingly enough in 3-d, it is not possible, and the bird that flies out of the cage, never returns.. or some such thing!

Comment: I think the comparison to the bird isn't quite correct, as it doesn't move around 'aimlessly': it searches out food, mating partners, avoids danger etc

Comment: Well, it is a very rough analogy. Obviously the bird does not move about in $Z^3$ does it.